# Deploy MDB using GenericJMSRA on GlassFish with annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, message-driven-bean, glassfish-2.x, ejb-jar.xml

On GlassFish Server 2.1 I have created a GenericJMSRA for connection with ActiveMQ as described in this guideline: http://activemq.apache.org/sjsas-with-genericjmsra.html

I have successfully been able to deploy an MDB using the the classical way of injecting the context with ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN'     'http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd'>
<ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
      <ejb-name>QueueListener</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>foo.QueueListenerMDB</ejb-class>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </message-driven>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

and sun-ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-ejb-jar PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 8.1 EJB 2.1//EN' 'http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-ejb-jar_2_1-1.dtd'>
<sun-ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <ejb>
      <ejb-name>QueueListener</ejb-name>
        <mdb-connection-factory>
          <jndi-name>jms/amqQueueConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
        </mdb-connection-factory>
        <mdb-resource-adapter>
        <resource-adapter-mid>activemqra</resource-adapter-mid>
        <activation-config>
          <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>DestinationType</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
          </activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>qRequest</activation-config-property-value>
          </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>
      </mdb-resource-adapter>
    </ejb>
  </enterprise-beans>
</sun-ejb-jar>
```

How would I go ahead injecting the above configuration in annotation driven EJB 3.0 style? More specifically it is the following property I can't find out how to inject:

```
<resource-adapter-mid>activemqra</resource-adapter-mid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work finally.

I removed ejb-jar.xml completely and left the sun-ejb-jar.xml untouched. Then I annotated the class foo.QueueListenerMDB as follows:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "QueueListener", mappedName = "QueueListener")
public class QueueListenerMDB implements MessageListener {
    ...
}
```